# Checking Angular Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Is there a way that I can confirm that a module has loaded the correct dependencies? I have included ngAnimate as part of the module definition, but it does not "seem" to be loaded into the application upon run time.  There are a multitude of complexities in the environment I am working in so I want to find a clear way of knowing if ngAnimate has in fact been loaded or not.

```
angular.module('test', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'other',
    'stuff'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inject $animate into one of your controllers and if you get an injection error you know it hasn't loaded.

You do know that ngAnimate needs to be loaded as a separate file, right?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, the actual animate js file is being loaded. I have injected as you said to test, .controller("testController", ["$scope", "$animate", ... and there are no errors given.  Since ngAnimate still isn't working I am going to assume it is something else besides Dependency Injection.

Comment: Yeah, ngAnimate can be tough to grasp...if you could put together a more detailed example in a plunkr or something I could try to help you, but at least now you know that the module is being loaded.